# Can you use sed to delete match and only certain lines after?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Is it possible to use sed to search for a particular block of code and delete the match and only a particular line after it?

For example, if I have a block like this, and want to delete special marker 1 and only the second line after it:

```
special marker 1
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

Can I use sed to search for instances of the block and come out with:

```
text 1
text 3
```

I am aware of commands like:

```
sed -i '/START/,/END/ {/special marker 1/{n;n;N;d;}}' filename;
```

However, this command only leaves me with:

```
text 1
```

So it seems to double the next line operation and deletes. Any way to fix this command or do this another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '/START/,/END/ {/special marker 1/{N;N;D};P;d}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the closest to what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Tell `sed` to print to skip the 2 lines:

```
sed -ni '/special marker 1/{n;p;n;n};p' filename
```

When you only want two lines output, the command can be replaced by

```
sed -ni '/special marker 1/{n;p;n;n;p}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '/special marker 1/{p=NR; next} p && NR==p+2{p=0; next} 1' file
text 1
text 3
```

Answer (score 1):

try following awk solutions too once.

**Solution 1st:**

```
awk '/special marker 1/{;if(getline var){print var;if(getline var1){next};next}} 1'   Input_file
```

**Solution 2nd:**

```
awk '/special marker 1/{getline;if(NF){print};if(NF){;getline};next} 1'  Input_file
```